# Can't Submit Form Using Jquery

Tags: php, html, jquery, form-submit

I need to know that what is the error in my code because everything is correct but form data could not be submitted and in php file the error popups that undefined index lname while submiting the form that means form is submitting through jquery but data is not going in backend. so please resolve this error or help me find out what the error is in code.

this is the html code:-

```
<span id="answer"></span>
            <form id='contact_form' method="post">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div id='name_error' class='error'>Please enter your name.</div>
                    <div>
                        <input type='text' name='lname' id='name' class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" required>
                    </div>

                    <div id='email_error' class='error'>Please enter your valid E-mail ID.</div>
                    <div>
                        <input type='email' name='email' id='email' class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email" required>
                    </div>

                    <div id='phone_error' class='error'>Please enter your phone number.</div>
                    <div>
                        <input type='text' name='phone' id='phone' class="form-control" placeholder="Your Phone" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" onclick="formSubmit(event);" class="btn btn-primary">I Agree</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

This is the jquery code:-

```
$('#subButton').click(function(e) {
        console.log('in');
        e.preventDefault();
        var FormData = $('#contact-form').submit();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "admin/backend/leads.php",
            data: FormData,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                var html = '';
                if (data.errors) {
                    html = '<div class="alert alert-danger">' + data.errors + '</div>';
                }
                if (data.success) {
                    html = '<div class="alert alert-success">' + data.success + '</div>';
                    $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
                    localStorage.setItem('#phone', true);
                }
                $('#answer').html(html);
            },
            error: function(data) {
                html = '<div class="alert alert-danger">' + data.errors + '</div>';
                $('#answer').html(html);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Did you include jQuery ?

Comment: yes it's version is 2.1.3 @DreamBold

Comment: `'#subButton'` doesn't exist in the HTML you shared, and your submit button is running a function that doesn't exist in your JavaScript code you shared `onclick="formSubmit(event);"`

Comment: Change your submit button code with this `<button id="subButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">I Agree</button>` and it will work! @Beast69

Answer (score 1):

Problems in your code are...

1. There is no element with `id="subButton"`
2. There is no `formSubmit` function
3. `$('#contact-form').submit()` submits the form normally which you don't want. It also returns a `jQuery` object, not the form data.

First, remove the `onClick` from your submit button.

```html
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">I Agree</button>
```

Second, either add `id="subButton"` to your `<button>` or, as is my preference, listen to the *submit* event on the form instead.

Third, use jQuery's [.serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to capture all the form data

```js
$("#contact_form").on("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const postData = $(e.target).serialize();

  $.post("admin/backend/leads.php", postData, null, "json")
    .done((data) => {
      // make HTML changes, etc
    })
    .fail((_, textStatus, errorThrown) => {
      // report error, etc
    });
});
```

---

It's 2022 and [you might not need jQuery](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

```js
document
  .getElementById("contact_form")
  .addEventListener("submit", async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const body = new URLSearchParams(new FormData(e.target));
    try {
      const res = await fetch("admin/backend/leads.php", {
        method: "POST",
        body,
      });
      if (!res.ok) {
        throw res;
      }
      const data = await res.json();
      // make HTML changes, etc
    } catch (err) {
      // report error, etc
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('#contact-form').submit(function(e) {
        console.log('in');
        e.preventDefault();
        var body = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "admin/backend/leads.php",
            data: JSON.stringify(body),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                var html = '';
                if (data.errors) {
                    html = '<div class="alert alert-danger">' + data.errors + '</div>';
                }
                if (data.success) {
                    html = '<div class="alert alert-success">' + data.success + '</div>';
                    $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
                    localStorage.setItem('#phone', true);
                }
                $('#answer').html(html);
            },
            error: function(data) {
                html = '<div class="alert alert-danger">' + data.errors + '</div>';
                $('#answer').html(html);
            }
        });
    });
```